# Create custom Kotlin annotation based on other annotation

Tags: java, spring, kotlin, jvm, jsr

I have a DTO, which is validated by Spring JSR validation, like this:

```
data class CreateDeckRequest(
    @field:NotBlank(message = "should not be blank!")
    val name: String?,
    @field:NotBlank(message = "should not be blank!")
    val techDesc: String?
    )
```

I am trying to reduce boilerplate and want my DTO to look like this:

```
data class CreateDeckRequest(
    @NotBlankApi
    val name: String?,
    @NotBlankApi
    val techDesc: String?
    )
```

To do that I want to create custom annotaion, which may look something like this:

```
@kotlin.annotation.Target(AnnotationTarget.FIELD)
@Retention(AnnotationRetention.RUNTIME)
@NotNull(message = "should not be blank!")
annotation class NotBlankApiField
```

Is that semantically possible?

Thanks!